# Hiding content in an org buffer

Tags: org-mode

Given an org document where some headers are visible and others
not, and some content is visble and other content not, how can I
hide all content, but leave the headers that were visible before
visible and those that were invisible before invisible?  If
there is no straightforward way of doing it, could one write a
function to that effect?

Comment: Maybe I haven't had enough coffee yet, but I don't understand what you are asking: an example might help.

Comment: Try pressing shift-tab a few times to cycle to the state you want.

Comment: @JohnKitchin, this will show all headers.
i only want to see the headers already visible.

Comment: I also don’t understand what you want then. An example of before and after might help.